# How to implement the notion of assets in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, assets, relation

I am currently building a database for different sensors and now i have to create assets. By asset, i mean group of sensors like in a room or a group of sensors of the same type.

The thing is : 1 sensor can be in Asset A (Machine 1) and Asset B (Machine 2). We can consider it to be a temperature sensor in a room containing the 2 machines.

What i want to do, is to link that sensor to the 2 assets and i don't really see how to do it and this is where i need some help.

In my database, i can give an Asset_ID, and going in the Asset_Table, i can link my sensor to ONE machine using the Asset_ID.

So, how can i link the sensor to 2 Asset_ID, so it will be associated with the 2 machines in my database

I hope this is a bit clear !

- Dave

Answer (score 1):

You want an `AssetMachines` table:

```
create table AssetMachines (
    AssetMachine_Id serial primary key,
    Asset_Id int references assets(asset_id),
    Machine_Id int references machines(machine_id),
    . . .  -- more columns can go here
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!

I created the tables, but i still have some questions. I haven't really worked with database so it is probably me that miss a basic concept.

But, from what i see. I can still only link the data of my sensor ton only 1 asset and only 1 machine if i am using my example?

And i would need a completely new entry in the database to be able to link the data with machine 2?

Here is the link for a screenshot of the structure : https://ibb.co/gz2G3sY

- Dave

Comment: @Dave  . . . Each relationship between an asset and machine would be a separate row in `AssetMachines`.

Comment: I understand that. Let me reformulate... maybe i said that wrong. But if you look at the table on the left,  "Physical_Sensor". The column Asset_Machine_ID will only be associated with 1 asset and 1 machine using the table "assetmachines" ? What if i want to associate the sensor to more than one machine in the same asset? Or are you suggesting that i create a machine_id for both machines? EX : 01 = Machine 1, 02 = Machine 2 and 03 = Machine 1 AND Machine 2?

Comment: There can be one entry per machine and asset

Answer (score 0):

I think the many-to-many relationship is best expressed by

```
CREATE TABLE assetmachines (
    asset_id integer references assets (asset_id),
    machine_id integer references machines (machine_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (asset_id, machine_id)
);
```